# Attaching to another process in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

Is there a way to attach my process to another process?
(for example, instead of opening the other process in with CREATE_PROCESS with some other flag?)
just like a debugger can do...
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for DebugActiveProcess.

Answer (score 2):

This is platform specific. On Unix it's usually [`ptrace(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html).